# Excluding a file from a gulp task not working

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a gulp task I've put together where I need to exclude a single file. The task is below. I've tried a few variations of exclusion like: `!+source...` and `source + '!sass/**/navigation-offcanvas.scss'`. Obviously my syntax is off. I looked at this article: https://discourse.roots.io/t/exclude-file-types-in-fonts-task/5356 and this: https://medium.com/@jack.yin/exclude-directory-pattern-in-gulp-with-glob-in-gulp-src-9cc981f32116 and still not quite there.

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
return gulp.src([
  source + 'sass/**/*.scss',
  !source + 'sass/**/navigation-offcanvas.scss'
])
```

Comment: did you try using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ignore

Comment: I didn't. I'm not using the package and I didn't want to bring it in for something that can be handled natively. I did try this as well: `'!' + source + 'sass/**/!(navigation-offcanvas.scss)'` and still no joy. The file keeps getting compiled into my main css file.

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/165

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The not `!` operator shall be within the string, in this way (the way you have it in the question), it is evaluating as a javascript call and not being evaluted within gulp.

```
 gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src([
      source + 'sass/**/*.scss',
      '!' + source + 'sass/**/navigation-offcanvas.scss'
    ])
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I did try that pattern and I'm still having the same issue. 
`gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src([
      source + 'sass/**/*.scss',
      '!' + source + 'sass/layouts/navigation-offcanvas.scss'
  ])`

Comment: try switching the the values in the array, making the excludes before the includes

Comment: This syntax `'!' + source + 'sass/**/!(navigation-offcanvas.scss)'` was right the whole time... Thank you. I was importing the sass file in another stylesheet... FML. Thanks again, once I removed the import the tasks ran and excluded what I wanted.